# Does C allow parameter by address?

Tags: c

I am getting a compilation error for the following statement:

```
void read_text(int & c1, int & c2, string file1, string file2 )
```

I seem to get error when passing the address; the error message is below:

```
Error   13  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'  \\vmware-host\shared folders\school\misc\johncpp\porj\similarity.c  101
```

I am using on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does allow passing a pointer, which is the usual mechanism for parameter references.  However, the syntax is not as used in C++, which you have used.   Instead it is:

```
void read_text(int * c1, int * c2, string file1, string file2)
```

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Agreed.  C++ adds a variation of pass-by-reference using the `&` which means a call need not take addresses of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is invalid in C.  I'm not sure what your aim is.  Either you're thinking of C++ references (which are a C++ thing), or you're thinking of pointers, in which case you want `*`, not `&`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use C++ style references in C.  You'll need to pass pointers to get similar behaviour.

Comment: I suppose that's possible, but do you really believe it?

Comment: there's always the possibility of `typedef char *string;`

Comment: yeah i had a line of typedef char* string;

Comment: Well, then I take that back. =)  I'll edit out that part of my answer.

Comment: that make sense, bummer that you cant pass by & in C. thanks a lot for the clarification :)