# invalid operands to binary / (have ‘float *’ and ‘int’)?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I need to pass by reference for my class. I'm getting the error in the title, but only for the functions divideByTweleve and multiplyByEleven. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? 
Please help me figure this out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void displayMenu();
float addTen (float* number);
float divideByTwelve(float* number);
float subtractSixteen(float* number);
float multiplyByEleven(float* number);
int menu;
float number, finalNumber;
float* ptr_number;

int main (void)
{
    float* ptr_number=NULL;
    ptr_number=&number;

    printf("Please enter a number : ");
    scanf("%f", &number);
    displayMenu();
    scanf("%d", &menu);

do {
    printf("\nEnter 5 to see final number\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu);
    switch (menu)
        {
        case 1: number=addTen(ptr_number); 
                break; 
        case 2: number=divideByTwelve(ptr_number);
                break; 
        case 3: number=subtractSixteen(ptr_number);
                break;
        case 4: number=multiplyByEleven(ptr_number);
                break;
        }
    printf("Your number is: %.2f \n", number);
    }while(menu!=5);//close of the do-while loop
}

void displayMenu()
{
    printf("How would you like to manipulate your number\n");
    printf("1. Add 10\n");
    printf("2. Divide by 12\n");
    printf("3. Subtract 16\n");
    printf("4. Multiply by 11\n");
}


float addTen (float* number)
{
    ptr_number=ptr_number+10;

}

float divideByTwelve (float* number)
{
    ptr_number=ptr_number/12;

}

float subtractSixteen(float* number)
{
    ptr_number=ptr_number-16;

}

float multiplyByEleven(float* number)
{
    ptr_number=ptr_number*11;

}
```

Comment: If you want a function to operate on a number and return a result as a return value, don't pass the address of the number, just pass the number. Also, your functions aren't returning anything although they are declared to return `float`.

Comment: In a function like `addTen`, why do you even pass in parameter `number`?  It is not used in the function.

Comment: If you're supposed to be passing by reference, get rid of the global variables and use the thing you passed in (hint: dereferernce it before you operate on it!)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of your (many) issues.

You declare `addTen` as:

```
float addTen (float* number);
```

And call it as:

```
number=addTen(ptr_number);
```

Which clearly indicates it returns a value.

Now, do you see a return statement in the function definition?

```
float addTen (float* number)
{
    ptr_number=ptr_number+10;   // No return statement!!
}
```

---

Next up, all your function take a `float*` as a parameter, which you should read as "Pointer to a Floating point number".  Note that a pointer is ***not*** the same thing as the value itself.

To get from a pointer to a value, you need to "de-reference" it:

```
float addTen (float* number)
{
    *ptr_number = *ptr_number + 10;
}
```

The star (`*`) before each `ptr_number` means to go from the pointer back to the actual value.

Before, you were trying to add 10 to a pointer.
(that is valid, but not appropriate in the current context)

Now, with the `*`, you're adding 10 to the value stored at the pointed-to location.

---

---

**Ultimately, here's my corrected version of your code**

```
void displayMenu();
void addTen (float* number);
void divideByTwelve(float* number);
void subtractSixteen(float* number);
void multiplyByEleven(float* number);


int main (void)
{
    int menu;
    float number;
    
    printf("Please enter a number : ");
    scanf("%f", &number);
    displayMenu();
    scanf("%d", &menu);

    do {
    printf("\nEnter 5 to see final number\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu);
    switch (menu)
        {
        case 1: addTen(&number);             break; 
        case 2: divideByTwelve(&number);     break; 
        case 3: subtractSixteen(&number);    break;
        case 4: multiplyByEleven(&number);   break;
        }
    printf("Your number is: %.2f \n", number);
    }while(menu!=5);//close of the do-while loop

    printf("Your FINAL number is: %.2f \n", number);
}

void displayMenu()
{
    printf("How would you like to manipulate your number\n");
    printf("1. Add 10\n");
    printf("2. Divide by 12\n");
    printf("3. Subtract 16\n");
    printf("4. Multiply by 11\n");
}


void addTen (float* ptr_number)
{
    *ptr_number = *ptr_number+10;
}

void divideByTwelve (float* ptr_number)
{
    *ptr_number = *ptr_number/12;
}

void subtractSixteen(float* ptr_number)
{
    *ptr_number = *ptr_number-16;
}

void multiplyByEleven(float* ptr_number)
{
    *ptr_number = *ptr_number*11;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, as you can see I'm still learning the very early stages of C. I'm still making the rookie mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not returning `float` values from these functions. If you want to pass a pointer to your functions then you should do this as

```
float divideByTwelve (float *)
{
    *ptr_number= *ptr_number/12;
     return *ptr_number;
}
```

But you have declared `number` as global variable, so no need to pass a pointer to these function. Just pass the `number` itself`;

```
float divideByTwelve (float number)
{
     return number / 12;
}
```

Comment: @chux; `float divideByTwelve (float* &number)` is passes by reference.

Comment: @chux; Yes. Try to run this test program: `#include <stdio.h>

void print_arr (int *p, int n)
{ 
 for (int *ptr = p; ptr < p+n; ptr++)
  printf("%d\t", *ptr);
}
int main()
{
 int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
 
 print_arr(&a[0], 3);
}`. You can see the output [here](http://ideone.com/RauX20).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37943/discussion-between-chux-and-haccks)

Comment: I maintain `divideByTwelve (float &number)` is not valid C syntax.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856248/does-c-allow-parameter-by-address/9856270#9856270

Comment: Suggest you want `float divideByTwelve (float *ptr_number)`.  I'm going to delete most comments as they no longer apply to your present answer.

Comment: @chux; I dropped `ptr_number` from declaration just because it is globally defined. But it is good practice to write parameter names :)